# Problems when compiling Objective C with Clang (Ubuntu)

Tags: objective-c, ubuntu, compiler-construction, linker, clang

I'm learning Objective-C language. Since I don't have a Mac, I'm compiling and running my code within Ubuntu 11.04 platform.

Until now, I was using gcc to compile. I've installed GNUStep and all was working. But then I started to try some Objective-C 2.0 features, like @property and @synthesize, that gcc does not allow.

So I tried to compile the code with Clang, but it seems that it is not correctly linking my code with the GNUStep libraries, not even with a simple Hello world program.

For example, if I compile the following code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(void) {
  NSLog(@"Hello world!");
  return 0;
}
```

The output of the compiler is:

```
/tmp/cc-dHZIp1.o: In function `main':
test.m:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `NSLog'
/tmp/cc-dHZIp1.o: In function `.objc_load_function':
test.m:(.text+0x3c): undefined reference to `__objc_exec_class'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
clang: error: linker (via gcc) command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

The command I'm using to compile is

```
clang -I /usr/include/GNUstep/ test.m -o test
```

with the -I directive to include the GNUStep libraries (otherwise, Clang is not able to find Foundation.h).

I've googled my problem, and visited both GNUStep and Clang web pages, but I haven't found a solution to it. So any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The problem was that the library gnustep-base was not being used by the linker. So the solution to this was using the option -Xlinker, that sends arguments to the linker used by clang:

```
clang -I /usr/include/GNUstep/ -Xlinker -lgnustep-base test.m -o test
```

The statement "-X linker -lgnustep-base" made the magic. However, I had problems with this command related to the class that represents a string in Objective-C:

```
./test: Uncaught exception NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: GSFFIInvocation:
Class 'NXConstantString'(instance) does not respond to forwardInvocation: for
'hasSuffix:'
```

I could solve it adding the argument "-fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString":

```
clang -I /usr/include/GNUstep/ -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString \
-Xlinker -lgnustep-base test.m -o test
```

In addition, I've tried with some Objective-C 2.0 pieces of code and it seems to work.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try gcc compiler:
First of all install GNU Objective-C Runtime: `sudo apt-get install gobjc`
then compile: `gcc -o hello hello.m -Wall -lobjc`

Comment: Hi URLArenzo. I have already installed that package, and tried gcc to compile (it was working perfectly). However, I figured out that gcc does not allow some features of Objective-C 2.0; so I'm trying to make things run with Clang compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You are not able to use ObjC 2.0 features because you're missing a ObjC-runtime supporting those. GCC's runtime is old and outdated, it doesn't support ObjC 2.0. Clang/LLVM doesn't have a acompanied runtime, you need to install the ObjC2-runtime from GNUstep (which can be found here: https://github.com/gnustep/libobjc2 ) and reinstall GNUstep using this runtime.

Here are some bash scripts for different Ubuntu versions, that do everything for you:

http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/GNUstep_under_Ubuntu_Linux

And please don't try to reinvent GNUstep make, instead, use it:

http://www.gnustep.org/resources/documentation/Developer/Make/Manual/gnustep-make_1.html

If you really don't think so, here is some excerpt from there:

1.2 Structure of a Makefile

Here is an example makefile (named GNUmakefile to emphasis the fact that it relies on special features of the GNU make program).

```
#
# An example GNUmakefile
#

# Include the common variables defined by the Makefile Package
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/common.make

# Build a simple Objective-C program
TOOL_NAME = simple

# The Objective-C files to compile
simple_OBJC_FILES = simple.m

-include GNUmakefile.preamble

# Include in the rules for making GNUstep command-line programs
include $(GNUSTEP_MAKEFILES)/tool.make

-include GNUmakefile.postamble
```

This is all that is necessary to define the project.

In your case replace all occurrences of `simple` with `test` and you're done

1.3 Running Make

Normally to compile a package which uses the Makefile Package it is purely a matter of typing `make` from the top-level directory of the package, and the package is compiled without any additional interaction.