# Objective C Compilation error in Ubuntu

Tags: objective-c

I am very new to Objective C. I just started with. I have downloaded objective C package and done all the steps exactly as in "http://wiki.gnustep.org/index.php/GNUstep_under_Ubuntu_Linux". I compiled the code also mentioned in the link. That works fine. However I have written very basic program just to print a message but I am getting compilation error.

/tmp/Chandan-59bf66.o: In function `main':
/home/chandan/Documents/Chandan.m:6: undefined reference to`NSLog'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Here is my code

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]){

@autoreleasepool{
NSLog(@"Hello World");
}
return 0;
}
```

Please guide me. Thanks in advance

Comment: It is a linker error. What are the flags passed to linker ?

Comment: Hi this is how I have compiled.  clang Chandan.m -o out `gnustep-config --objc-flags` `gnustep-config --objc-libs` -fobjc-runtime=gnustep -fblocks -fobjc-arc -lobjc.

Comment: I suppose you should link with Foundation framework, `-framework Foundation`. Just guess, I don't have any experience in ubuntu.

Comment: No that doesn't work.

Comment: @Chandan Try as mentioned in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9337265/problems-when-compiling-objective-c-with-clang-ubuntu).

Comment: Hi that is giving new problem.   clang -I /usr/include/GNUstep/ -fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString -Xlinker -lgnustep-base Chandan.m -o test
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/../../../libgnustep-base.so: undefined reference to symbol 'objc_msg_lookup'
//usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libobjc.so.4: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking you need more flags for compiler. Here's mine:

```
clang   $1\
-MMD \
-MP \
-DGNUSTEP \
-DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 \
-DGNU_RUNTIME=1 \
-DGNUSTEP_BASE_LIBRARY=1 \
-fno-strict-aliasing \
-fexceptions \
-fobjc-exceptions \
-D_NATIVE_OBJC_EXCEPTIONS \
-pthread \
-fPIC \
-Wall \
-DGSWARN \
-DGSDIAGNOSE \
-Wno-import \
-g \
-O2 \
-fgnu-runtime \
-fblocks \
-fobjc-nonfragile-abi \
-fconstant-string-class=NSConstantString \
-I . \
-I /GNUstep/System/Library/Headers/ \
-L /GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries/ \
-lobjc \
-lgnustep-base \
-lgnustep-gui \
-ldispatch
```

Comment: I got my problem solved. I have to add -lobjc flag. Compilation problem solved. Theres one more problem created. That is some compatibility issue. I will see to it myself. Thanks all